# Gulp 4 не создает sourcemaps для js

Tags: javascript, gulp, sourcemap

Gulp 4 выполняет функцию но sourcemaps для js файлов не создается

Код:

```
function scripts() {
    return src([ 
        themePath + '/inc/js/template.js'
    ], {sourcemaps: true})
        .pipe(concat('template.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify()) 
        .pipe(dest(themePath + '/inc/js', {sourcemaps: '.'}));
}
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Перевидите на русский язык или задавайте вопрос на [английской версии сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/) но вообще у вас проблема что вы sourcemap не верно вызываете [gulp-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps)

Comment: Зачем использовать gulp-sourcemaps когда есть встроенный в сам gulp?

Comment: @Vladsg 0.0 не видел, его в 4-м Гулпе добавили. Все что нашел это [src()](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src/#sourcemaps) но не понятно где описание

Comment: Проверил в своем проекте все должно работать как вы записали, ошибки какие то есть?

Answer (score 0):

Установите зависимость `gulp-sourcemaps` и подключите её в `gulpfile.js`. А потом:

```
function scripts() {
    return src([ 
        themePath + '/inc/js/template.js'
    ])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('template.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify()) 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(dest(themePath + '/inc/js'));
}
```